Webscoket in angular 17
Help, I don't know how to use websocket in angular 17
I try with socket.io and pusher, but my proyect didn´t work
I look in a lot of pages but no one works. I did the api and the websocket conection on Laravel, the angular part is the only one that I can´t.
I find a lot of pages where they made it with another angular versions,
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import  as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {
constructor() {}

private subject: Rx.Subject\<MessageEvent\>;

public connect(url): Rx.Subject\<MessageEvent\> {
if (!this.subject) {
this.subject = this.create(url);
console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
}
return this.subject;
}

private create(url): Rx.Subject\<MessageEvent\> {
let ws = new WebSocket(url);

let observable = Rx.Observable.create((obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
  ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
  ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
  ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
  return ws.close.bind(ws);
});
let observer = {
  next: (data: Object) => {
    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }
};
return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);

}
}
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

@Component({
selector: 'app-cancel',
templateUrl: './cancel.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./cancel.component.css'\]
})

export class CancelComponent implements OnInit {
pusher:any
echo:any
constructor(){
this.pusher = Pusher;
this.websocket();
}

websocket(){
this.echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: "GoofNBCH",
cluster: "mt1",
forceTLS: true
});
console.log(this.echo)    
}
}


Eyy, bro, me too
